Resolving TensorFlow AttributeError: Missing 'register_load_context_function'

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.internal' has
no attribute 'register_load_context_function'. Did you mean:
'register_call_context_function'?

I am done with update tensorflow and other library but its showing error

Could be broken env. Maybe try to reinstall tensorflow in a clean env. This could help.
